# Express.js index.js 404 (Not Found)

Tags: node.js, express

For some reason it can't load my index.js script that is being referenced from my index.html.  server.js, index.html, and index.js are all located at the root of my project folder.

**server.js**

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express();

app.set("view options", {layout: false});
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.set('views', __dirname + '/');
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.set('view engine', 'html');

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('index.html');
});

app.listen(4000, function () {
    console.log('Example app listening on port 4000!');
});
```

**index.html**

```
<html>
    </head></head>
    <body>
        <div class="ink-grid vertical-space">
            <div id="content">
                <div class="panel vertical-space">
                    <div id="app"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/babel" src="index.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: to render on html use res.render('index', { message:""});

Answer (score 4):

You have to serve those files. You could do them individually:

```
app.get('/index.js', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile('index.js');
});
```

Or create a directory (e.g. `www`) for everything you want to serve and use `express.static`:

```
app.use(express.static('www'));
```

Answer (score 2):

By looking declaration

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

Your `index.js` file should be in the `public` directory.

Since `index.js` and `server.js` are in the same directory, define

```
app.use(express.static(.));
```